# Split a column in Numbers by extracting text in parenthesis

Tags: numbers

I need to extract everything from "ORIGINAL COMBINED" that is between parenthesis and place it in the SPLIT A and place the remainder in the SPLIT B column. For example:

[image]

Comment: To clarify... I really just need to be able to extract any numbers that are enclosed with parenthesis and add them to a new column so that I can run some queries with just those numbers.

Comment: Are you looking for the number alone in the new column, or should it be enclosed in parentheses as your screenshot suggests?

Comment: Either option would suffice as I could do a find and replace if I need to remove the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this task, we need to use a combination of `Text` functions in our formulas. [*See Apple's documentaiton for more details on using these functions.*](http://help.apple.com/functions/mac/7.2/#/ffaef5aeec8)

***TL;DR the formulas are beneath the explanation.***

So we need to identify the `(XX)` in each text string.  In one column, display only the parens and numbers between them, and in the other column, omit them.  This will require combining several text functions into a single fomula.

## 'Split A' Column

In the original 'string' each character has a position starting at 1.  So for example in the following string, the `(` has a position of 3.

`1 (23) Large Broom`

So what we need to determine is at what position is `(` and `)` in each string.  We can use `Find()` to do this.
`FIND(search-string, source-string, start-pos)`

So using the example string above:
`=FIND("(", "1 (23) Large Broom")`
returns: `3`

Then we can use `FIND()` to get the positon of `)` too.  In this case it returns the position of `6`.
We can now use this with the `MID()` function to retreive the number with parens.

```
MID(A2,FIND("(",A2),FIND(")",A2,)
// Where A2 contains our original text
result: (23)
```

Now, if there are no `()` we will get an error so to handle this we wrap the whole formula in the `IFERROR()` function.  If there is an error return an empty string.  (or anything you wish)

```
IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("(",A2),FIND(")",A2,),"")
```

Paste this formula in your 'Split A' column.

### 'Split B' Column

We can use the `REPLACE()` function to substitue an empty string for our number in parens.  So this: `(23)` becomes this: `""`. (The quotes won't show.)
`REPLACE(source-string, start-pos, replace-length, new-string)`

To remove the `(23)`, we need to add `1` to the position of `)` then subtract the position of `(`.  So in this case `7 - 3` to get `4`, the length of our number/parens string.

```
REPLACE(A2,FIND("(",A2,),(FIND(")",A2,)+1−FIND("(",A2,)),"")
```

Breakdown:

```
REPLACE(
  A2, ← the source string cell reference
  FIND("(",A2,),
    (FIND(")",A2,)+1−FIND("(",A2,)), ← resulting in 4
"") ← replace with empty string
```

Wrap this also in a `IFERROR()` and now the result is `1  Large Broom`  (Note the extra space.  This can be eliminated if we add 2 instead of 1)

**TL;DR** - So here we are. Whew! the formulas with our nested functions to solve this:

**Split A**

```
IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("(",A2),FIND(")",A2,),"")
```

**Split B**

```
IFERROR(REPLACE(A2,FIND("(",A2,),(FIND(")",A2,)+1−FIND("(",A2,)),""),"")
```

[image: Table]

[image: Table with formulas animation]